# Подгрузка Webp вместо jpg во всех браузерах где он поддерживается, в остальных подгружать jpg

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, .htaccess

Ребят, привет. Подскажите как сделать подгрузку webp вместо jpg в тех браузерах где он поддерживается. Использовал способ - https://github.com/vincentorback/WebP-images-with-htaccess , но jpg всёравно грузиться на сайте вместе с webp. Мне нужно сделать так чтобы jpg вообще не грузился, а грузился только Webp. В тех браузерах где он не поддерживается естественно иначе. Буду благодарен за помощь!

```html
<picture>
    <source data-srcset="img/test-mob.webp" media="(max-width: 576px)" type="image/webp">
    <source data-srcset="img/test-mob.jpg" media="(max-width: 576px)">
    <source data-srcset="img/test.webp" type="image/webp">
    <img data-lazy="img/test.jpg" alt="test" class="lazy">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю у тебя грузится webp проверить можно в devtools вкладка network.
Еще атрибут должен быть "srcset" а не "data-srcset" если у тебя
Lazyload возможно стоит пересмотреть js код.